# How to debug go fuzzing?

Tags: go, debugging, goland, fuzzing

I am trying to debug the fuzzing part in golang sdk (go/internal/fuzz) with GoLand, with a demo like this:

```
package awesomeProject1

import "testing"

func fn(s string) int {
    var sum int
    for _, i := range s {
        sum += int(i)
    }
    return sum
}

func FuzzFn(f *testing.F) {
    f.Add("hello")
    f.Fuzz(
        func(t *testing.T, s string) {
            fn(s)
        })
}
```

It works fine when I **run** or **debug** it without breakpoint:

```
=== RUN   FuzzFn
fuzz: elapsed: 0s, gathering baseline coverage: 0/8 completed
fuzz: elapsed: 0s, gathering baseline coverage: 8/8 completed, now fuzzing with 6 workers
fuzz: elapsed: 3s, execs: 2041388 (679470/sec), new interesting: 0 (total: 8)
```

However, when **debug** with a simple breakpoint at whether `f.Add` or `f.Fuzz`, it hangs:

```
=== RUN   FuzzFn
```

So how can I debug it?

I have tried to set the breakpoint inside the sdk, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using Go 1.20 with GoLand 2022.3. This version of GoLand ships with Delve that supports Go versions up to 1.19.

You can either change your project to target Go 1.19 or use the [EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/) of GoLand that includes an updated version of Delve.